# Access unbound combobox has bound column value but won't display unbound value

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010

I am using a query to set the value of a combobox, which uses a query for the row source. The query will return a code such as "ADDD" which corresponds to "Accidental Death, Dismemberment and Disability Benefit". The code is in column 1 of the combobox, but is set to a width of 0. The description is in column 2, and is what should be displayed. I have figured out that the combobox value is correctly being set to the code, but the description isn't being displayed. If I replace the query result with "ADDD" then it works correctly, and displays the description.

```
        strSQL = "SELECT SchemaBenefit FROM Benefit_Client WHERE SchemaName = '" & cboSchema & "' AND SchemaBenefitClient = Me.ben1

        rs.Open strSQL, cnn

        With Me.acf1
            If rs.EOF = False Then .Value = rs.GetString
        End With
```

EDIT:

let me try and explain a little better. I have a table that contains about 1400 claim codes and their corresponding description. I use this as the source for 30 comboboxes. Column 1 of the combobox is the code, is hidden, and is the bound column. Column 2 is the description. I then have a second table that stores the scheme/template. When I query this scheme/template table I return the code as the result, but I want the combobox to display the description

EDIT 2:

Simplified code to use just 1 combobox as example

Comment: This is very difficult to answer with the limited information provided. Access is hard to work with here because a lot of the coding work is already done for you. But your question doesn't match with the code you presented. The code shows only one column being returned in your SQL statement. You aren't going to have a "Column 2" because you don't have 2 columns being returned from your query.

Comment: Check the `Bound column` property for the combo box.  Make sure it says `1`.  Check the property also for number of columns.  It's hard to understand what your code is doing... can you put what is found for `Control source` for the combo box?

Comment: I think you may need to add a 'rs.movefirst' if not EOF?

Comment: @BoydP let me try and explain a little better. I have a table that contains about 1400 claim codes and their corresponding description. I use this as the source for 30 comboboxes. Column 1 of the combobox is the code, is hidden, and is the bound column. Column 2 is the description. I then have a second table that stores the scheme/template. When I query this scheme/template table I return the code as the result, but I want the combobox to display the description.

Comment: @Smandoli it is bound to column 1, column count is 2, and `control source` is                                                                                     `SELECT rga_Benefits.ITEM_CODE, rga_Benefits.ITEM_DESCRIPTION FROM rga_Benefits WHERE (((rga_Benefits.ITEM_CODE)<>"")) ORDER BY rga_Benefits.ITEM_DESCRIPTION;`

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be too specific to my question, and if so please delete it. But my issue was that the rs.getstring was returning the correct string, but also an empty line after the text. When I used left(rs.getstring, 2) it fixed my problem.